# Knowing about Sensor Film Kit

Tags: electrochemistry, materials

I am very new to this site and this is my first ever question. I want to know what is [this black material](http://www.sensorfilmkit.com/) in this sensor film kit. I am creating a weight sensor by using this very sensor kit. Now I am short of this black film. I want to purchase it now locally but do not know the composition of this material.
This material behaves as a resistance between two aluminium foil, just to inform.
If any one can help me in this.

Comment: This really should be on the electrical engineering section. // I don't know what specific material this is, but Google "Conductive foam" and you should find some. The resistance changes as the foam is squeezed.

Comment: @Max In this case I agree that it would probably better fit another site. But I am only one. Before asking to migrate something it would be preferable if the question is closed by the community. Then I will research if it is a good fit for the target site. Still, thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a force sensing resistor. It's basically a film of small conductive particles mixed into a non-conductive polymer matrix on top of a conductive substrate. The more force on the film, the more conductive particles can touch the layer underneath, reducing the resistance. Sensitronics owns the original patent for the technology and their [site](http://www.sensitronics.com/fsr101.htm) shows how they're constructed, though you'll probably have to dig up the patent to find out exactly what's in the force sensing layer.